# Wolfram Mathematica solving a particular equation

Tags: variables, wolfram-mathematica, equation, subscript, wolframalpha

I'm using Wolfram Mathematica 8 and I want to make it solve this equation for the variable t:
[image]

It probably involves using variables with longer names and having subscripts

Comment: Please post the code you tried so far

Comment: I've  tried Subscript[x,2] but it doesn't recognize it, it thinks that "subscript" is a word, and gives me lexical information about it, like  dictionary definition and so on.

Comment: Don't use subscripts. See the fourth point here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/193

Comment: Are you talking about Wolfram Alpha or something?? I've never seen mathematica give lexical info on anything.   FWIW mathematica solves your quadratic just fine  with Subscript[].  (Not to disagree that subscripts are liable to cause you other greif.)

Comment: If your post your code (as @belisarius rightly suggests), try also to give it to us in FullForm.

Comment: tell us the action you take to execute and the the exact error message too...

Answer (score 2):

I have tried to type your equation in Mathematica 8 and it was solved.

Here the input (in FullForm)

```
Solve[(Subscript[x, 2] + Subscript[Speed, Subscript[x, 2]]*t - 
  Subscript[x, 1] - 
  Subscript[Speed, Subscript[x, 1]]*t)^2 + (Subscript[y, 2] + 
  Subscript[Speed, Subscript[y, 2]]*t - Subscript[y, 1] - 
  Subscript[Speed, Subscript[y, 1]]*t)^2 == (Subscript[r, 1] + 
 Subscript[r, 2])^2, t]
```

Here is the result (as an image because the FullForm is too long to be informative)

[image: Result of Solve with subscripts]

Hope this example will help you find what went wrong in your case.

Comment: It solved it when I typed it in the Kernel, but still no solution when I type it in a notebook (.nb).

Comment: @user763852 : it might point to a problem with the configuration of the *Front End* (fonts, kernel options, keyboard, language, internet interaction, etc.) You certainly need to try it on another machine, another OS, another version or try to reset your Mathematica Front End preferences.